# Event tracking in Google analytics is not displaying events data

Tags: google-analytics

I am adding Google Analytics code in my website, it displays active users but not but displaying the event list empty.

I tried both below codes

1)

```
jQuery('.btn-cart').click(function() {


ga('send', 'event', 'add-to-cart', 'add','product-added-to-cart');

});
```

2)

```
onclick("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'whitepaper', 'add', 'product-added-to-cart']);")
```

[image]

Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
jQuery('.btn-cart').on('click',function() {
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Add to Cart', 'Add To Cart Clickthrough', '<?php echo $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();?>']);

});
```